# How to override values.yaml from parent chart in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install **rabbitmq** helm chart in `dependencies` section of my parent chart.
Here is my parent chart

```
apiVersion: v2
name: mychart
description: A Helm chart to install rabbitmq
type: application
version: 1.0.0
appVersion: "1.0.0"
dependencies:
  - name: rabbitmq
    repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
    version: 8.11.9
    condition: rabbitmq.enabled
```

And here is the values.yml file of this chart

```
rabbitmq:
  enabled: true
  auth.username: test
  auth.password: test
```

I am trying to override the values of `auth.username` and `auth.password` of rabbitmq dependency chart. But values are getting override. And default values are used when I deploy/test this chart.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `helm install --set` option takes options like `--set rabbitmq.auth.username=...`, and charts' documentation generally uses this syntax, in YAML files you need to put each part in a nested block:

```yaml
rabbitmq:
  enabled: true
  auth:
    # "username" under "auth", not a single key "auth.username"
    username: test
    password: test
```